# Should I Add Something To The Header File?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, uicollectionview

I'm writing an app and getting this error. Not sure how I would go about fixing it. Thank you.

The error is an undeclared identifier 'collectionView'

And the header file is being imported.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSMutableData *content;

@interface AMCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *tagButton;

- (IBAction)tagButtonTouched:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation where error is occurring

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if(shareEnabled){
        //determine the selected items by using the indexPath
        NSString *selectedPhotos = [tagImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath];

        //add selected image into the array
        [selectedPhotos addObject:selectedPhotos];
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot guys

I use collectionView multiple times in the same .m file

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 50;

}
```

---

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *identifier =@"Cell";

        AMCollectionViewCell *cell = (AMCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 10;



        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageicon%d.jpg",imageNumber]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageBorder.jpg"]];


        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Are you `#import`ing your header (.h) in the implementation (.m) file?

Comment: Please add error to the question using `edit`

Comment: You have something called `collectionView` that hasn't been declared anywhere. How do you think your declaring and initializing `collectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that error, but

1. Your second reference to `indexPath` on this line can't be right:

   ```
   NSString *selectedPhotos = [tagImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath];
   ```

   The `objectAtIndex` parameter needs an integer. You probably meant:

   ```
   NSString *selectedPhotos = [tagImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
   ```

   or, to be more consistent (either use `objectAtIndex` or use the `[]` syntax, but using both is a little curious):

   ```
   NSString *selectedPhotos = tagImages[indexPath.section][indexPath.item];
   ```
2. You haven't shown the declaration of `tagImages`, nor it's initialization, but I assume it is `tagImages` an array of an array of strings? If so, the above correction should fix it. If not, you should tell us how `tabImages` is populated/structured.
3. If `selectedPhotos` is a `NSString`, the use of the `addObject` method won't possibly work. The `addObject` method is a `NSMutableArray` method, not a `NSString` method.

Comment: I implemented all of the changes you suggested, and my only error is still the undeclared identifier 'collectionView'

Comment: @user2469203 At which line of code is it showing you that error? Perhaps you can update your question with the current code, as well as a clear indication as to which line of code is generating that error.